# MySQL Database Architecture.. Create a table of properties that are common for different table for easier edit in future

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am new to DB design. I am currently designing a schema that has

**Customer Table :**

name | phone | email | password | address_one | address_two | city | street | postal | country

**Outlet Table :**

name | phone | address_one | address_two | city | street | postal | country

**Account Table :**

name | phone | address_one | address_two | city | street | postal | country

Is it a good idea to separate address_one, address_two, city, street, postal and country to a new table called Address Table. Even though their relationships are one-to-one like the one mentioned below.

**Address Table :**

address_one | address_two | city | street | postal | country

The reason why I want to split this into a new table is because in Code level, I would like to create a Model and have methods that are specific to the Address Table. So in future when any attribute of the address model changes I can change this table alone, and it will change all the three mentioned tables Customer, Outlet and Account. Instead of adding individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

From performance perspective - no, that's not the best idea.

Although it's going to pop up only at pretty large volumes and/or with very tough response time requirements.

From the architectural perspective, especially in case when address could be reused by more then 1 referring entities, and/or ever processed separately in whatever manner - yes, that makes sense (and that seem to be more or less your case).

Basically, you're already answered your own question yourself right within the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I was also thinking from the performance point, that I will have a join every time I create a query. Then I realised from your point, I need to check how often the table is used vs how often the table data will be changed. And it makes sense to duplicate the data, as the table will be used more often than the change in data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What will you do with the Address?  Will you simply transfer the fields to an envelope?  If that is all, it can be a single column, with new-lines in it.

Or will you search for Outlets in a certain Country?

On the one hand, it is important to lay out the columns that need to be in a schema.  On the other hand, it is really important to think about the queries that will be applied to the schema.

Anyway, 1:1 is rarely a good idea.

Your Address table, if you go that way, needs an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I will have a requirement to search for outlets from a certain country. The address will be used to to calculate lat long, check the distance for the customer and outlet, group all the outlets pertaining to a city or state.  I was planning to use UUID for all tables in my schema.

Comment: If you have a single database generating ids, don't use UUIDs; they have several problems in the long run.

Comment: It's going to be slow to check the lat/lng distance for one customer against all the rows.  How many rows do you expect?  Anyway, that is a topic for another Question.

Comment: Yes I agree. Thats another topic. 
I am expecting a few hundred thousand rows.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the lat/long calculation on the server side. So assuming that the customer orders from an outlet, I will retrieve both the customer and the outlet, both having a child Address table. Then use them to calculate the lat/long. This eliminates the need to check lat/long for one customer against all rows, right?

Comment: Correct.  I was afraid you were asking for "the closest Outlet for a given Customer".  In any case, you should include lat & lng as two more columns wherever the Address is.  I suggest `FLOAT` for each; that is simple and will give you resolution of 1.7 m or 5.6 ft.

Comment: Thats awesome! Will implement that. Thanks a lot for your help, Rick.